# Set manually a value in inputpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this [plugin for inputpicker](http://www.inputpicker.com/www/)

```
<input class="form-control" id="test" value="2" />
<script>
$('#test').inputpicker({
    data:[
        {value:"1",text:"Text 1", description: "This is the description of the text 1."},
        {value:"2",text:"Text 2", description: "This is the description of the text 2."},
        {value:"3",text:"Text 3", description: "This is the description of the text 3."}
    ],
    fields:[
        {name:'value',text:'Id'},
        {name:'text',text:'Title'},
        {name:'description',text:'Description'}
    ],
    autoOpen: true,
    headShow: true,
    fieldText : 'text',
    fieldValue: 'value'
    });
</script>
```

How to select a value manually for this inputpicker?
I tried

```
$("#test").val(2);
```

But visually nothing is displayed

Comment: https://github.com/ukalpa/inputpicker/issues/31 - Did you put `$("#test").val(2);` after your inputpicker initialisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the way JavaScript is working causing this issue, specifically, setting value on an input does not trigger change event. You can test:

Assume $0 is an input element

```
$0.onchange = function(){ alert('1') }
$0.value = '123';
```

No alert will appear. Same behavior applies to jQuery's .val() function.

Therefore you need to trigger change event yourself, i.e.

`$("#test").val(2).trigger('change');`

Then inputpicker will be able to actually pick up the change.